# Using permutation importance after a pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to apply a PCA to my features to solve the multicolinearity and then use the principal components in a random forest classifier for a binary classification. Permutation importance gives me the importance of my original input features, which I know is the expected behaviour, but is there anyway of using permutation importance within my pipeline to get the importances of the transformed features? I want to do it within the pipeline as I plan to use nested cross validation in the future and want to avoid data leakage.

Reproducible code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
# define dataset
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=20, n_informative=15, n_redundant=5, random_state=1)
# summarize the dataset
test_pipeline=Pipeline(steps=[
                   ('pca', PCA(n_components=8)),
             ('random_forest_classifier', RandomForestClassifier())
])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, stratify=y)
test_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

feature_importance_results=permutation_importance(test_pipeline, X_test, y_test, scoring='roc_auc')
#print(feature_importance_results)
forest_importances = pd.Series(feature_importance_results.importances_mean)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I want to do it within the pipeline as I plan to use nested cross validation in the future and want to avoid data leakage."; are you wanting to get different importances across different folds?