# Permutation feature importance on features transformed within a pipeline (sklearn)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, pca, feature-selection

A similar issue [has been raised earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76573990/using-permutation-importance-after-a-pipeline). I need to compute feature importance of **preprocessed features** via `sklearn.inspection.permutation_importance`. The preprocessing is implemented within a pipeline. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

###
data load
###

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(all_features, diagnosis, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

pca_conn = Pipeline(
    steps = [("group_whiten", StandardScaler()),
             ('pca_conn', PCA(n_components = 100)),
            ("pca_whiten", StandardScaler())]
)

pca_grad = Pipeline(
    steps = [("group_whiten", StandardScaler()),
             ('pca_grad', PCA(n_components = 100)),
            ("pca_whiten", StandardScaler())]
)

pca_centroid_disp_pca = Pipeline(
    steps = [("group_whiten", StandardScaler()),
             ('pca_grad', PCA(n_components = 10)),
            ("pca_whiten", StandardScaler())]
)

pca_cortex_disp_pca = Pipeline(
    steps = [("group_whiten", StandardScaler()),
             ('pca_grad', PCA(n_components = 100)),
            ("pca_whiten", StandardScaler())]
)

cat_encoder = Pipeline(
    steps = [("cat_encoder", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"))]
)
whiten = Pipeline(
    steps = [("whiten", StandardScaler())]
)

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("pca_conn", pca_conn, conn_cols),
        ("pca_grad", pca_grad, grad_cols),
        ("pca_centroid_disp_pca", pca_centroid_disp_pca, centroid_disp_cols),
        ("pca_cortex_disp_pca", pca_cortex_disp_pca, cortex_disp_cols),
        ("encode_dataset", cat_encoder, ["dataset"]),
        ("encode_sex", cat_encoder, ["sex"]),
        ("whiten_fd", whiten, ["mean_fd"]),
        ("whiten_age", whiten, ["age"])
    ]
)

lr = LogisticRegression(random_state=42, max_iter = 10000)
clf = Pipeline([('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                ('lr',lr)])

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

trained_logreg = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
trained_logreg.score(X_test, y_test)

perm_acc = permutation_importance(trained_logreg, X_test, y_test,n_repeats=100, random_state=42, n_jobs = -1)
```

It looks like permutation importance is computed for raw features by default. Has anyone tried implementing permutation importance for transformed features? Any tips? I assume that doing preprocessing separately is not an option (data leakage).

Comment: What data leakage would there be?  (That's off-topic here, better at stats.SE or datascience.SE, but the programming question could maybe still be answered if it's determined how exactly you need/want permutation importance to be measured mid-pipeline?)

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/62106204/10495893

Comment: The general advice is to keep transformations within pipelines so that only the train set is transformed prior to the model fit. As far as I understand if I first transform the all features and then fit the model, I go against this advice. In my case permutation importance of the original features is not feasible since the raw dataset contains over a million features. Hence the need to do feature importance on the transformed data.